# Solution of given complex functional equation:

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function

Consider the following functional equation:

$F(x+iy)-F(x-iy)= (e^{ay}-1)f(x,y)$

$f(x,y)$could be any function depending on $F$

> What is the general solution to this type of functional equation?

Any reference/s where I can study about such problems are also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using the Euler Lagrange equation  on $F(z)$?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz No,i haven't